# grabbing tomcat startup time

Tags: tomcat, startup

I'd like to grab tomcat's "Server Startup in XXms" (in http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/Catalina.java) and log it elsewhere.

Is there a way to either grab that value or a hook to wrap the start() function? I don't need the exact number, but it needs to be reasonably close.

I'd prefer not to grep the catalina log if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/listeners.html?

I think you can achieve your goal by adding your own [LifecycleListener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/LifecycleListener.html) implementation underneath the Server or Engine element in server.xml

Your listener could then implement any timing mechanism you think is convenient, and log it any way you like.

Hope this helps!